# Is there an equivalent to the windows GetSystemTimes() function in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

In Windows there is a function called [GetSystemTimes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms724400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that returns the system idle time, the amount of time spent executing kernel code, and the amount of time spent executing user mode code.

Is there an equivalent function(s) in linux?

Comment: better place to ask:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @foampile I think SO is quite well-suited for this question actually since it's programming-related.

Comment: foampile - This is a programming question not a general unix question.

Comment: I'm not sure that asking for exact equivalent of Windows API function makes sense in general, even if for this particular case it makes sense. Notice that `times(2)` also return child time (but don't return idle time).

Comment: Basile - it's not so much a case of finding an exact equivalent function.  Sometimes it is a single function, a bunch of functions or there isn't one and you have to fake it.  It's a very common thing when porting code from one platform to another. This is why I asked the question because I had a utility that prints out some timing in windows and I want the same utility in Linux if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original answer gave a solution to getting the user and system time of the current running process. However, you want the information on the entire system. As far as I know, the only way to get this information is to parse the contents of `/proc/stat`. In particular, the first line, labeled `cpu`:

```
cpu  85806677 11713309 6660413 3490353007 6236822 300919 807875 0
```

This is followed by per `cpu` summaries if you are running an SMP system. The line itself has the following information (in order):

- time in user mode
- time in user mode with low priority
- time in system mode
- time idle
- time waiting for I/O to complete
- time servicing interrupts
- time servicing software interrupts
- time spent in virtualization

The times are reported in units of `USER_HZ`.

There may be other columns after this depending on the version of your kernel.

Original answer:

---

You want [`times(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times):

> `times()`  stores  the  current  process times in the `struct tms` that `buf` points to.  The `struct tms` is as defined in `<sys/times.h>`:

```
   struct tms {
          clock_t tms_utime;  /* user time */
          clock_t tms_stime;  /* system time */
          clock_t tms_cutime; /* user time of children */
          clock_t tms_cstime; /* system time of children */
   };
```

Idle time can be inferred from tracking elapsed wall clock time, and subtracting away the non-idle times reported from the call.

Comment: I also suggest reading http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html and http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/